# Cursor position: can you determine screen position for print command in Python 3.4 in a Windows 7 environment?

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I'm quite new to programming but enjoying my first steps in Python 3.4.3

I am trying fix a certain screen/print position - is that possible? I believe in Unix you can use tput is there something similar for Python in Windows environment?

In other words: is there a command that determines (x, y) coordinates for printing a variable? I.e. something like: 4 lines down, 5 positions to the right?

Reason for asking: I want a count down clock while not clearing the whole screen with `os.system('cls')`

Comment: Windows doesn't come with a utility to position the console cursor. The APIs for this are `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` and `SetConsoleCursorPosition`. But it would probably be easier for you to use the [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) module to write ANSI sequences such as `print('\033[4B\033[5C' + '4 down (B), 5 forward (C)')`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun - not sure if I understand though - is the ANSI sequence supposed to position some text 4 lines down and 5 forward? I ran the code and it did not seem to do that - I think I missed the point of your comment?

Comment: @newb, you need to install the `colorama` module and then replace `sys.stdout` by calling `colorama.init()`. The new `stdout` decodes ANSI sequences into console API calls. Then the example I gave should print the text "4 down (B), 5 forward (C)" positioned 4 rows down and 5 columns forward. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `tput` utility provided with Windows.  But you can develop [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx) scripts which use the features of the Windows [Console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Here are a few links which illustrate that:

- *[Hey, Scripting Guy! Interacting with the Windows PowerShell Console Window](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/26/hey-scripting-guy-march-26-2010.aspx)*
- *[Position the cursor in Powershell](http://www.mickputley.net/2013/06/position-cursor-in-powershell.html)*  (which moves the text-cursor)
- *[Moving Cursor to Specific Location](http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/moving-cursor-to-specific-location.html)*  (again, move the cursor and print)
- *[Moving the Mouse Cursor with Windows PowerShell](https://flamingkeys.com/2011/03/moving-the-mouse-cursor-with-windows-powershell/)*